# Configuring ServiceNow through a program

Tags: java, servicenow

I need a custom definition of ServiceNow for my business. For which, I'll have to configure many tables like Incident, CIs to name a few, then the views, forms etc. I am aware that it can be done through UI provided at our instance. But doing it through a program which can configure our definition on a fresh instance in one go will be a challenge.

But I think it should be possible, to give you a scenario here's what I might be doing..

-- I need to create new views on a table, new fields on that view, adding dependent fields, new choices in the choice list for a choice field and the list goes on...

Is there any way to do it in Java? maybe using JSON Web services provided by ServiceNow? 
Or is there any API in java which can simplify the work, like the one for BMC Remedy?

I understand that it is a big task, please let me know if there is any other way to do it.

PS: I am familiar with the JSON web service API available for ServiceNow.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do some kind of bootstrapping or standard configuration *on top of* an Out-Of-Box ServiceNow instance? If so, your best bet is probably to package an Update Set with that standard configuration, and then export the XML for the Update Set using the "Export Update Set" UI Action, which you could deploy as desired to any target instance.

Comment: I read about Update sets, I found dependencies on versions, instances etc., cannot guarantee those matches. Also these has to be done through UI. I am trying to do it through a program. Since Update Set is an XML file, can I create an Update Set of my own? and instead of importing through UI can I make this one too through program, maybe a POST operation on a corresponding table?
Or, my first idea was to insert the records through web-service since the fields, choice-lists, views are all tables. Will those be reflecting in the instance? How do I set a view on a table to get my customized form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Joey. It sounds like a vanilla use case for Update Sets.

Comment: I read about the Update sets and they are a good option to me if they can be done without any UI intervention. If possible please tell me how to. Also refer my reply to @Joey, will that other idea work out?

Comment: I am not aware of any method that can be used to apply an update set other than via the UI. I think this is a product limitation. They ought to support a Web Services API for Update Sets, but if it exists it is not documented anywhere.  I would contact ServiceNow Tech Support directly via their HI system and ask this question.

Comment: p.s. In theory it should be possible to make coding changes via the Direct Web Services API. Everything is stored in database tables and any table can be updated via the API. However, it would be hard. You could do something simple like updating a choice list, but updating a form would be very complex. Form layouts are spread across a half dozen tables. You need an intimate understanding of the data model, and it is not documented anywhere.

Comment: I've implemented such configuration through Direct Web Service calls. Creating new fields, choices in the choice list, table. I tried hard to create views, forms, sections but it doesn't satisfy me completely. Anyway, thank you for your consideration!